# how to create water like they did in LIMBO game using the cocos2d and box2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have seen this before, and making my research i've discovered that if you create allot of circles objects in box2d, then apply a color, then blur it and at the end sharp it a little bit ( same stile like "Where is my water" game created by disney ).

But of course in a game like limbo, with a huge world this is extremely expensive.
Since i have seen this in a few games over the internet i still trying to understand how can i build this with box2d ? ( the games over the internet where/are created with in flash, and i want to do it in cocos2d for the iOS platform )

a few examples about how the water works, for those that didn't played the Limbo game:
1.A box will flow on the water, the box will enter in the water only half of it and half of the box will will remain above the water. If an object (like: the player ) will falls above it the box will have the end of the titanic, it will sink.

2.A rock will sink.

3.The player, well i guess here will be different choices.

4.A boat, for the bout i know a bool should do the trick `BOOL canSink;` but again how should i make that water effect ? balancing the object on it, an bouncing if the object falls in the water, and for sinking a slower velocity ?

It may look like allot of questions,but at the end is only the " How to create the water effect in box2d?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you're looking for buoyancy effects, here you have a couple of interesting resources.-

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/buoyancy
http://personal.boristhebrave.com/project/b2buoyancycontroller/demo

As for the water waves effect, you can take a look at.-

http://www.sideroller.com/wck/?f=6
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/25494

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is it!  thank you very much. you have gave me the right answer (the first link is just great ). thanks again !

Comment: i can't vote for your answer, so please everybody who read this answer give him a big vote!